# Can't change the size of icon in button HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to make my icon in my button bigger.
I've looking up but can't figure out how.
This is my code.

```html
<div class="row mb-5">
  <div class="col">
    <button class="btn btn-info text-white">
      <span class=" icon-format_list_bulleted mr-1 wrap-icon"></span>
      <br />
      Inventory
    </button>

    <button class="btn btn-info text-white">
      <span class="icon-cutlery mr-1 wrap-icon"></span>
      <br />
      Meal
    </button>

    <button class="btn btn-info text-white">
      <span class="icon-library_books mr-1 wrap-icon"></span>
      <br />
      Report
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try with font-size?

Comment: @Andrej Font size for icons? How do I do that?

Comment: In css: `.wrap-icon {font-size: 24px;}`

Comment: Give the span holding the icon a font size. The underlying code for font awesome icons is that the icons are text characters. `<span style="font-size:32px"></span>`

Answer (score 0):

The icons are actually characters in a special font (remember WingDings?). So they can be formatted with font related style attributes such as font-size, color, font-weight, line-height, etc. In this case:

```
.btn-info span {
  font-size:32px;
}
```

Think of icons like this:

```
.my-icon.wrap-icon::before {
  content: "a";
  font-family: Webdings!important;
}
```